# Google App Script - Send Mail from Google Form (needs subject line variable)

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm new to google app scripting, and there's a lot i'm struggling to understand here.

i'm using this script below.

i'm trying to take a line from the form submission (that states the location of where it was submitted from) and add it to the email SUBJECT line that is sent by this script. this will allow me to sort in my email box by the location they are submitted from.

here are the contents below. is there an e.value i need to use? do i need to define another variable and add it with a + to the subject string?

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{ var email = "workemails@mydomain.com";
var subject = "Maintenance Submission Form"; 
var message = ""; for(var field in e.namedValues) { message += field + ' :: ' + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
} MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate it with the existing subject like this:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) { 
    var email = "workemails@mydomain.com";
    var subject = "Maintenance Submission Form"; 
    var message = "";
    for(var field in e.namedValues) { 
        message += field + ' :: ' + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
    }
    //get location from field named locationFieldNameGoesHere and 
    //prepend it to the standard subject line
    subject=e.namedValues['locationFieldNameGoesHere'].toString() + subject;
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
}
```

Comment: nate from kalamazoo, i owe you a beer. this worked perfectly.

Comment: If you ever swing through Michigan, we can stop by the Olde Peninsula Brewpub. In lieu of that, an upvote/accept will do just fine ;)

Comment: when my rep is less lame, i'm on it